# Does TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED make sense for retrieving entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, jpql

Does having `TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED` on every DB lookup method makes sense? I don't see the point in having the entity attached if it's not going to execute an update.

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
pubic List<AnEntity> getListEntities(){
    TypedQuery<AnEntity> query = em.createNamedQuery("AnEntity.myQuery",AnEntity.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Does it still end up in the cache?

The only time it seems useful to use the `REQUIRED` transcation propagation is when an update is required:

```
 @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
 public void editPersonName(Integer id, String newName){
      AnEntity anEntity= em.find(AnEntity.class, id);
      anEntity.setName(newName);
 }
```

Other than that I don't really see the point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it doesn't make sense to use the `NOT_SUPPORTED` transaction propagation for read-only queries, but it makes a lot of sense to use the default `REQUIRED` transaction propagation. You also need a transaction for reading data. The database always uses a transaction, no matter if you specify it or not.

Using an explicit transaction allows you to group several statements in a single transaction, and, if you are using Hibernate, you might avoid the aggressive connection release overhead.

Just because JPA allows you to execute read queries without a transaction, it doesn't mean you have to do it this way.

The `NOT_SUPPORTED` mode is useful when you want to execute a service method outside of the current transaction scope. For example, when you have methods that don't need a transaction at all (e.g sending an email) so that you avoid the overhead of starting/ending a transaction context.

Comment: Strange mention - "The NOT_SUPPORTED mode is useful when you want to execute a service method outside of the current transaction scope" and "No, it doesn't make sense to use the NOT_SUPPORTED transaction propagation for read-only queries, but it makes a lot of sense to use the default REQUIRED transaction propagation" . First of all if you will perform read query inside of transaction then you will get the updated but not committed state of entities which were modified inside this transaction prior to the query and it's might be not the desired case

Comment: Second - if you really want to execute this method out of transaction scope as it stated, then you wrote is 'yes', useful, but from other side you says 'no'.